# Is there a similar site to this for moviemaking, film design, visual effects, etc?

Tags: movies, film, moviemaking, visuals, effects

I discovered this site through a friend who is into sound design. I love the Question/Answer format of this site.  It acts a lot like a forum, but the better answers are easier to find and view, unlike having to search through a convoluted forum post that can often be filled with trolls and crap answers.

My question is: Is there a site(s) that mirrors this format for film, film design, visual effects, etc? Either a sister site to this site, or a different site altogether, I would just love to have a strong resource for film and visual effects/compositing/editing.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This actually existed for a couple years when this question was asked: https://video.stackexchange.com/

Enjoy!